# Git 1 and 1 commit after rebase aborted

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

So I commited (but not pushed) some of my work and then another colleague pushed his changes. To get his changes I did

git pull --rebase

Then there was a conflict in one of the files but I figured I better do it when he is around so I did:

git rebase --abort

Now the message I see is:
Your branch and 'origin/featureBranch' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.

How do I get this to be fine now?

Comment: you local branch is fine.. It just has more info about the remote branch.. and its basically saying that you have made 1 commit  which is different than the 1 commit on the remote branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your coworker returns, type

```
git rebase origin/featureBranch
```

and you can tackle the conflict together.

Or if you want to minimize your git vocab, you can always just repeat your original command `git pull --rebase` which will do the same thing (plus a needless extra fetch, but maybe you favor the simplicity of one command over the efficiency of two more precise ones).